# How to call key events internally in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, keydown, keyevent

When press Enter key,
I want to perform the following operations internally.

1. Enter the 'Space key'
2. Enter the 'Backspace key'

```js
editor.on('keydown', function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            // I want to coding this part.
            // 1. keypress keyCode(32) == Space
            // 2. keypress keyCode(8) == Backspace
          }
        });
```

The reason for this is that the editor is not compatible with the IME keyboard.
So I wonder how to input keys internally.

Comment: Enter the 'Enter key'   might cause infiinite loop.

Comment: @ArunKumarMN Thank you for your feedback. I will modify the contents a bit.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Host Listener?

To listen to the window for events, we will use the `HostListener` API. This API allows us to register a particular listener for events in the browser and then call methods in our components to react to them.

Here a sample code:

Html:

```
<button (click)="decrement()">-</button>
{{value}}
<button (click)="increment()">+</button>
```

Ts:

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export enum KEY_CODE {
  RIGHT_ARROW = 39,
  LEFT_ARROW = 37
}

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  value = 0;
  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);

    if (event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.RIGHT_ARROW) {
      this.increment();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.LEFT_ARROW) {
      this.decrement();
    }
  }

  increment() {
    this.value++;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.value--;
  }
}
```

Check this [blogpost](https://coryrylan.com/blog/listening-to-angular-key-events-with-host-listeners) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But Enter key recognition is implemented.